# TP1/TP2 equivalent for Raspberry Pi 3 B

Tags: pi-3, voltage

Is there "old" TP1/TP2 equivalent for Raspberry 3 Model B to measure voltage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [official schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-3B-V1.2-Schematics.pdf) show that:

- PP1 and PP2 are 5V input from USB
- PP35 is 5V after the polyfuse
- PP7 is 5V after the input circuit
- PP3 through PP6 are GND

They are to be found on the bottom side of the PCB near the Micro USB (power in) connector (that is on the top side of course).

Comment: My readings on are: PP1/PP2: 5.4V; PP35: 5.39V; PP7: 5.34V - hope thats OK :)

Comment: The voltage levels are a little bit on the higher end of the spec, but in real live nothing to worry about. The Pi is not using 5V directly and I wouldn't lose any sleep about peripherals connected via USB. Thanks for the pic by the way., @madneon.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [@Ghanima's great answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/77750/79326) I made markings on those +5V points:

[image]